Respective billing numbers in the saved search of respective purchase orders
I have a saved search to display all the purchase orders, with their document numbers, date created etc., and i also have to show the billing date of the those purchase orders with there respective billing numbers. Any inputs in terms what should be the criteria or options chosen in Results so that i can display the respective Bill Number and Bill date according to the purchase order  in Netsuite
Bill number and bill Date

Please edit the question to include information about what you have already tried, like if there is code, and also sample of data so that it's possible for others to help you out.
